# What is a cheap standard/wide prime lens for Canon APS-C?

Tags: lens, canon

50mm f/1.8 is said by many to be a great lens for its price, and one worth buying. On the other hand with a APS-C sensor it is rather long for my taste.

Is there some cheap lens **around 30mm or below** that is worth buying and has the good value like the 50mm f/1.8?

I would consider also some old manual lens if its quality justifies it.

Comment: +1 on what @drew said. Plus, most Canon crop sensor cameras have focus screen that are terrible for manual focus. On some models, you can change to a focus screen with some manual focus assist (micro prism, etc.) but you need to include the cost of the focus screen in your budget.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking for a fast prime that is the equivalent to 50mm on APS-C, you are looking for the Sigma 30mm 1.4. There is also the Canon 28mm 1.8, but it is slower and slightly softer than the Sigma, while being a tad more expensive.

The downside is that the Sigma runs about $450, so not really cheap. Unfortunately, there is no fast, cheap, wide angle prime like the nifty fifty.

But I think the Sigma is what you are looking for.

Comment: I would also recommend the Sigma 30 f/1.4.  I've heard so many good things about it.  On a Canon APS-C it would be the equivalent of 48mm (more or less your fifty!)

Comment: +1 for the Sigma 30mm. I've used it as my only lens for the last ~8 months and been very, very happy with it.

Answer (score 5):

At the time of this question, the accepted answer (suggesting the much more expensive Sigma 30mm as the best option) was true.  However, now I think users with this question would be interested in the Canon EF-S 24mm f/2.8 STM Lens that is running around 150 USD.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Sigma has a maximum aperture of f/1.4 which will let in 4x as much light as the Canon f/2.8. They each have their purpose of course. The Canon is a great value indeed. The question did not specify what max aperture they desired so this is still a good recommendation - they did say "has a good value". I'm not sure if that was "value" as in money or "value" as in max aperture.

Comment: @dpollitt to be more specific: "has the good value like the 50mm 1.8" , which i think is a combination of price and aperture (which they also said "cheap").  Im not sure if there is some function or ratio of aperture per dollar with a focal length factored in, but it would be neat if there was

Answer (score 2):

**Canon 40mm 2.8 STM** is your answer. I used to have a 50 1.8 which I also find very long and slow&loud focusing. 40 2.8 STM is focusing fast silent and has a wider FOV. Also has a great build quality and resoably priced. To see my shots visit my page: http://www.burcincemarabacioglu.com.tr/photography/pigeons.htm

I love my 40 2.8 STM :)

Comment: This is an "Ok" recommendation but 40mm is so similar to the 50mm that the user already has. I would caution against both in the same bag(although I do own one of each) unless the user is quite sure that is what they want.

Answer (score 1):

The 50 F1.8 is about $100. There are no Canon lenses that are wide, say 30 or even 24 that are fast (say F2.0 or better) and that inexpensive.

Most folks on crop bodies go for the 10-22 zoom, or one of the third party equivalents.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing for a $100 bucks.  Personally, and this is only a matter of personal opinion, I find the bokeh on this lens very noisy; to me it looks as cheap as the lens feels.

**If you don't mind all manual** you could try one of the Rokinnon/Samyang lenses:

[Rokinon 14mm f/2.8 IF ED MC Super Wide Angle Lens for Canon](http://www.rokinon.com/product.php?id=12) **$349**

[Rokinon 35mm f/1.4 Wide Angle Lens for Canon DSLR Cameras](http://www.rokinon.com/product.php?id=170) **$499**

[Rokinon 24mm f/1.4 ED AS UMC Wide-Angle Lens for Canon](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/819786-REG/Rokinon_RK24M_C_24mm_f_1_4_ED_AS.html) **$699**

Or the oh so extreme:

[Rokinon 8mm f/3.5 Aspherical Fisheye Lens for Canon DSLR Cameras](http://www.rokinon.com/product.php?id=7) **$299**

These are B&H prices.  Things don't really get cheaper than this.

Comment: At least two of those don't qualify as "cheap" in my book.  At those prices, you might as well go for the [Sigma 30 f/1.4](http://www.amazon.com/Sigma-30mm-Canon-Digital-Cameras/dp/B0007U0GZM/) and have auto-focus too.

Comment: True, if AF is important and if you are planning on staying with a cropped sensor then the Sigma makes sense. The Rokinnon manual lenses are not for everyone (manual aperture, diaphragm) However, aside from the autofocus, on paper, the Rokinnon 35mm 1.4 seems better in just about every department.

Answer (score 1):

Not mentioned, but one of the cheaper options is slightly more mm then 30mm. It is the canon 35mm f2.  Not the new version with IS, but the old one. Actually very comparable to the nifty fifty in build quality as well, then again, you get what you pay for. I would save some extra money and get the sigma 30mm f1.4.

Among the cheaper options there is also the 28mm f2.8, but this is not really a fast lens anymore, so i don't see an advantage over say the tamron 17-50mm.